# list data from dynamoDB local table to html using node.js and express

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-dynamodb, ejs, dynamo-local

I'm trying to List items from DynamoDB local to html table using node.js and express,
DynamoDB data goes like this:

`{"Items": [{ "id": "A004","name": "ACC LR2","userId": ["1","2","3","4"], {"id": "0001","name": "ABG IT","userId": [ "8","9","10","11"]}}]}`

My nodejs routes goes like this:

```
router.get('/groups', function(req, res, next) {
      var params = {
    TableName: 'userGroup',

};
dynamodb.scan(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    else { 
        console.log("These are Groups: "+ console.log(JSON.stringify(data.Items)));
     res.render('groups',{_uG : data.Items});

  }
}); 

});
```

my table on the html goes like this:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>user id</th>
    </thead>
  <tbody>     
    <% for(var i = 0; i < _uG.length; i++) { %>                           
  <tr class="gradeA even" role="row">
            <td class="sorting_1"><%= _uG[i].id.S %></td>
            <td><%= _uG[i].name.S %></td>
            <td><%= _uG[i].userId[i].L %></td>
  </tr>
         <% } %>
      </tbody>
</table>
```

console.log shows results like this:

```
{"id":{"S":"A004"},"name":{"S":"ACC LR2"},"userId":{"L":[{"S":"7"},{"S":"8"},{"S":"9"},{"S":"10"},{"S":"11"}]}}
```

I am able to list items of id and name , but I'm not able to list userID , what do I do to list userID on the html table?? .. help is appreciated ..

Answer (score 0):

It looks like userId is an Array of Objects so you need to iterate over it and get the string value of each object. So I would change the line where you render the userId to something like this:

```
<td><%= _uG[i].userId.L.map(function(item) {return item.S;}).join('') %></td>
```

Comment: What is the output when you run that? Do you expect userId to be "7891011"?

Comment: different columnS? or a 7891011 should be in the same column? I read your other question and still don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: please check this page , which is exacltly what i am trying to do...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33678695/how-to-select-an-element-from-json-array-and-display-on-html-using-nodejs